# Do electrons define the element?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, neutrons, protons

In a nuclear reaction, protons and neutrons are exchanged and the resulting elements have a number of different protons and neutrons that uniquely define the element that we are studying.

However, can we say that a hydrogen atom without any electrons (what we would usually call an ionised atom of hydrogen) is really hydrogen? Or do electrons fundamentally indicate the element that results from the reaction? Can we really say that an atom of hydrogen without electrons is actually hydrogen?

Comment: It is very clear in basic chemistry texts that it is the proton number that defines the element involved, and the electrons determine the ionic charge. This is the scheme that has proved to be practical.

Answer (score 4):

The number of protons defines the element. The number of electrons matter, but it doesn't magically turn an element into another element. For example O$^{2-}$ has a filled outer orbital, but it doesn't behave like a noble gas.

A hydrogen ion without any electrons still behaves as H$^{+}$ and not as He$^{2+}$, Li$^{3+}$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> However, can we say that a hydrogen atom without any electrons (what we would usually call an ionized atom of hydrogen) is really hydrogen?

Yes.  Or we can — with equal validity — say it's a proton.  Similarly, we can say that an alpha particle is just that, or it's a fully ionized helium nucleus.

> Or do electrons fundamentally indicate the element that results from the reaction?

Nope.  Because if you have $n$ protons and $n \pm m$ electrons, then the *nucleus* is still the same, and it's the charge of the nucleus that (primarily) drives the chemical reactions that are possible.

Add to this the fact that a nitrogen atom that's got an extra electron doesn't act *at all* like a neutral oxygen atom, and ditto for any other combinations of ionized/un-ionized atoms with differing nuclei and the same number of electrons.

> Can we really say that an atom of hydrogen without electrons is actually hydrogen?

Yes.  Because the behavior of naked protons is that at less than inside-of-a-star temperatures, they retain their essential "hydrogen-ness" even if they're ionized.

Answer (score 0):

I do not consider a proton to be an ionized hydrogen atom, since when I dealt with them, they were either a target being blasted by electrons/positrons (and it did not matter which), or they were in a beam pipe moving at relativistic speeds.

Now if you take a macroscopic bunch of them in equilibrium with their electrons, say: in a stellar nebula, then it's hydrogen.

So it's all context.