# Can you have “Anti-ionised” atoms?

Tags: electrons, charge, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry

I was looking at this question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/773528/263465), and there is a  mention $O^{2-}$ (oxygen atom with double negative charge).

This made me think, *is this possible?* That is, can you have an atom retain more electrons then it has protons? If yes for how long and how many?

Comment: Most (but not all) elements have a stable -1 charge state ion. No double minus ion is stable in vacuum and rapidly decay by ejecting an electron.

Comment: $H^{-}$ (i.e. a proton with two electrons) is a major contributor of the opacity function in stars, but only stable in larger numbers (as dynamic balance between formation and destruction) under high pressure plasma conditions.

Comment: The usual salt structure has a stable ionic lattice. If you consider MgO, then it has Mg$^{2+}$ and O$^{2-}$ in a simple cubic lattice.